# how the Try catch finally block is executed by JVM

Tags: java, try-finally

According to Java Language Specification, [Section §14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally
>     block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes normally.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S

If I interpret it correctly then after execution of try block finally is invoked, But how all this works and why I got the output,

```
public static int TestTryFinallyBlock()  
{
    int  i =0;
    try 
    {
        i= 10; //Perform some more operation
        return i;
    }       
    finally
    {
        i = 40; 
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    int i1 = TestTryFinallyBlock(); //Here the output was 10 not 40
}
```

I want to know how this thing produced output 10.

> **Is that when try block is executed and return statement is encountered the output value is already pushed to stack, and then the finally block is executed**

I know that return is encountered first then finally blocks runs so output is 10, but
**How jvm interpret or how the try finally block is handled or converted by jvm?**
Is that jvm uses GOTO section jump section to go to finally section or the stack is already maintained?

Comment: is the try / catch / finally executed by the compiler or by the jvm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little search and seeing what byte codes were generated, I found that actually there are no finally blocks as it seems and no jump or goto statements generated by JVM.
The above code is translated something as **(if I interpret byte code correctly, If I am wrong please do correct me)**

```
public static int TestTryFinallyBlock()  
{
  int returnValue; //A temporary return variable
  try
  {
     int  i = 0;     
     i = 10; 
     returnValue = i; 
     i = 40; 
     return returnValue;    
  }
  catch (RuntimeException e)
  {
       i = 40; //finally section code id copied here too
       throw e;
  }
}
```

**Point to Note:** If `'i'` would have been a reference to a mutable class object and the contents of the object were changed in the finally block, then those changes would have been reflected in the returned value too.

Answer (score 2):

### Compiling Finally

Compilation of a try-finally statement is similar to that of try-catch. Prior to transferring control outside the try statement, whether that transfer is normal or abrupt, because an exception has been thrown, the finally clause must first be executed. For this simple example:

```
void tryFinally() {
    try {
        tryItOut();
    } finally {
        wrapItUp();
    }
}
```

the compiled code is:

```
Method void tryFinally()
0   aload_0             // Beginning of try block
1   invokevirtual #6    // Method Example.tryItOut()V
4   jsr 14              // Call finally block
7   return              // End of try block
8   astore_1            // Beginning of handler for any throw
9   jsr 14              // Call finally block
12  aload_1             // Push thrown value
13  athrow              // ...and rethrow value to the invoker
14  astore_2            // Beginning of finally block
15  aload_0             // Push this
16  invokevirtual #5    // Method Example.wrapItUp()V
19  ret 2               // Return from finally block
Exception table:
From    To      Target      Type
0       4       8           any
```

There are four ways for control to pass outside of the try statement: by falling through the bottom of that block, by returning, by executing a break or continue statement, or by raising an exception.

To know more about how javac interprets the finally block .Please refer JLS - [3.13. Compiling finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13)

Comment: I want to know how stacks are maintained or how try finally block is converted by compiler? This is just example by me I do not need output 40

Comment: This is valid only for class files with version number 50.0 or below. [3.13. Compiling finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13)

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the return, the method is already prepared to return 10. 10 is on the stack as the return value. The finally block is executed and sets `i` to 40--but that `i` is not the same location as the return value. Now if there's a side effect like:

```
public static int TestTryFinallyBlock()  
{
    int  i =0;
    try 
    {
        i= 10; //Perform some more operation
        return i;
    }       
    finally
    {
        i = 40; 
        System.out.println("local: "+i);
    }
}
```

40 *will* be printed.

Comment: I want to know how stacks are maintained or how try finally block is converted by compiler?

Comment: @dbw: I would suggest you compile you code, then disassemble it with [`javap -c`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) to see the individual bytecodes. Read through this with a copy of the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/) to hand (particularly the sections on the structure of [frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) and the [Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html)) to learn *exactly* what is happening.

Comment: @hexafraction your links did helped me to find exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way the return statement function and the way it interact with a try with finally statement.

The [Section §14.17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) of the JLS describe the return statement.

> A return statement with an Expression attempts to transfer control to the invoker of the method that contains it; the value of the Expression becomes the value of the method invocation. More precisely, execution of such a return statement first evaluates the Expression. If the evaluation of the Expression completes abruptly for some reason, then the return statement completes abruptly for that reason. If evaluation of the Expression completes normally, producing a value V, then the return statement completes abruptly, the reason being a return with value V.

The last sentence indicates that if the expression of the return statement is *evaluated* normally, then the return statement completes *abrutptly*.  In your example, the `try` block terminates abrutply because of the `return` statement and the reason being a `return` value 10 (`i` is *evaluated* to value 10).

Since in your example the `return` is in a try with finally block, [Section §14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) of the JLS tells us what happens next:

> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason
>     R, then the finally block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for  reason R.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes bruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

So, since the `try` block terminated abruptly because of the return statement being *evaluated* to value 10, and because the finally block completes normally, then the method returns 10.

Answer (score 0):

Now the value of **i**  is 40  but you are not getting **40**, because you got(`returned`) the value before making it **40**.

it's like

```
i=10
return i
i=40
if return here,you get 40
```

Though not a good practice, Just for demo.

```
public static int TestTryFinallyBlock()  
    {
        int  i =0;
        try 
        {
            i= 10; //Perform some more operation

        }       
        finally
        {
            i = 40;
            return i;
        }
    }
```

Now the value of **40** you'l get in **i**.

**As a side note:**never write any business logic other than resource clean up. That's kills readability and causes bugs.

Comment: I want to know how stacks are maintained or how try finally block is converted by compiler? This is just example